# Angularjs Page contents change according to pages set in routers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create very simple website with AngularJS

I have a controller:

```
NGLesson.controller('Pages_Contents', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.homePage =
                {
                    pageURI: 'home',
                    pageName: 'Home',
                    pageDescription: 'Bla bla bla',
                    pageContent: 'Bla Bla Bla Bla blabla'
                };
        $scope.aboutPage =
                {
                    pageURI: 'about',
                    pageName: 'About',
                    pageDescription: 'Bla bla bla',
                    pageContent: 'Bla Bla Bla Bla blabla'
                };
            // And so on...
    }]);
```

I have router rules:

```
NGLesson.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/content-container.html',
                    controller: 'Pages_Contents'
                }).
                when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/content-container.html',
                    controller: 'Pages_Contents'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/something-else.html'
                });
    }]);
```

I also have basic template templates/content-container.html. But I do not know what parameters to put inside of it. This one works: **{{homePage.pageContent}}** but of course only for the homepage.

I also tried with different controller at first, but it appeared that I had to set different controllers in the **when()** function in the router. That meaned different templates and it was some kinf of stupid.

I cannot figure it myself. Is there any simple solution? Can you give me some advices? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different controllers but it's suggested.

Typically you'd create an HTML template and augment it with Angular for dynamic content.

If you have static content you may as well include it in the template not in Angular.

You can do this for your about page.

```
NGLesson.controller('About_Contents', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.aboutPage =
                {
                    pageURI: 'about',
                    pageName: 'About',
                    pageDescription: 'Bla bla bla',
                    pageContent: 'Bla Bla Bla Bla blabla'
                };
            // And so on...
    }]);
```

And then add this controller to your router configuration and `ng-controller="About_Contents"` to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

The proper route configuration should look like:

```
NGLesson.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'
                }).
                when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'about',
                    controller: 'aboutController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                   redirectTo: '/home'
                }));
    }]);
```

usually you have one controller/template per each route